# How can I create a selection that can show my total of objects by owners?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

i'm iniciating on sql and i have this sentence:

```
select owner, object_name, object_id, object_type, status, last_ddl_time 
from dba_objects;
```

That's show me all objects but i want something like:

- User SECURITY
- Tables: #
- Views: #
- Triggers: #
- Invalid Triggers: #

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT
    owner,
    SUM(DECODE(object_type, 'TABLE', 1, 0)) "Tables #",
    SUM(DECODE(object_type, 'VIEW', 1, 0)) "View #",
    SUM(DECODE(object_type, 'TRIGGER', 1, 0)) "Triggers #",
    SUM(CASE WHEN object_type = 'TRIGGER' AND status = 'INVALID' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "Invalid Triggers #"
FROM dba_objects
GROUP BY owner
```